# search a string in a file and operate on the line in perl

Tags: perl, csv

```
qa1 /apps/dir1 qavm01,qavm02,qavm03
qa2 /apps/dir2 qavm01,qavm02,qavm03
qa3 /apps/dir3 qavm01,qavm02,qavm03
cpz /apps/cpz1 ctg201,ctg202
```

I have a file as above.

1. I want to find the line that matches `qa1`. This will change each time, depending on what the user enters. I have an HTML front end for providing the value. I want the CSV pattern in an array so I can use it for the next operation.
2. Using a loop I need to connect to each server (the CSV pattern in the file is a list of servers) and access the directory.

I am new to Perl. I can do the second one. But I'm not sure how I can do the first part.

Comment: What are `qa1` etc.?

Comment: qa1, qa2, qa3, cpz etc are environments. The user selects that from a form on the front end html. qa1 has 3 servers associated with it. I need to make some changes under /apps/dir1 on these 3 servers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you as a basic framework

Note that it's up to you to write the part that gets the environment name into the `$input` variable, and the connection to the server

```perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use constant ENV_FILE => 'env_data.txt';

my $input = 'qa1';

open my $fh, '<', ENV_FILE
    or die sprintf qq{Unable to open "%s" for input: $!}, ENV_FILE;

LINE:
while ( <$fh> ) {
    next unless /\S/;
    my ($env, $dir, $servers) = split;
    next unless $env eq $input;

    for my $server ( split /,/, $servers ) {

        ## Connect to $server and access $dir

        last LINE;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick help.. But I am getting only one server in the $servers for some reason.. Any thoughts on why its like that.

Comment: @RahulR: Do you perhaps have spaces between them as well as commas? Like `qavm01, qavm02, qavm03`

Comment: @RahulR: I'm sorry, I made a mistake in my code. Try it now